# Check if Apps exists in the PowerBI workspace

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

I am using the following API to retrieve apps from the PowerBI workspace. Although I can confirm their presence through the user interface, I am encountering issues when trying to fetch them via the API.

```
# Create the HTTP request
$ListAppsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/apps" -Headers $headers -Method Get

# Filter the apps by workspaceId
$appsInWorkspace = $ListAppsResponse.value | Where-Object { $_.workspaceId -eq $workspaceId }

$updateAppInTargetWorkspace = Get-AppsList -workspaceId $workspaceId -accessToken $accessToken
```

But when using the SP, I encountered below error:

> "Invoke-RestMethod : {"Message":"API is not accessible for application"}"

According to Microsoft's documentation, I have granted the `App.Read.All` permission to the service principal utilized for authentication. I am sure the SP has access to PowerBI as the same SP is being used to deploy Datasets, Reports and updating the parameters and connections as well..

Below is the screenshot of the API permissions.

[image: API Permissions Provided]

Comment: Could you include how you are generating the access token? You have to grant **Power BI** permission not Microsoft Graph.

Comment: I am using below code for Authentication.       

`$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($AppId, (convertto-securestring $AppSecret -asplaintext -force))
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credentials -Tenant $tenantID

# Get the access token from the authenticated session
$accessToken = Get-PowerBIAccessToken
$accessToken = $accessToken.Values
 
$headers = @{
        "Authorization" = "$accessToken"
        "Content-Type" = "application/json"
 }`

Comment: As mentioned in this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/apps/get-apps#limitations), service principal authentication **isn't supported** for listing installed apps of Power BI via API.

Comment: You need to connect to PowerBI interactively as a user in order to fetch the list of installed apps.

Comment: Thanks for the Response. I will figure out a way to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> As mentioned in this [**MS
> Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/apps/get-apps#limitations),
> service principal authentication **isn't supported** for listing
> installed apps of Power BI via API.

When I ran your PowerShell script in my environment, I too got **same error** as below:

```
$AppId = "appId"
$AppSecret = "client_secret"
$tenantID = "tenantId"
$workspaceId = "workspaceId"

$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($AppId, (convertto-securestring $AppSecret -asplaintext -force))
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credentials -Tenant $tenantID

# Get the access token from the authenticated session 
$accessToken = Get-PowerBIAccessToken
$accessToken = $accessToken.Values
$headers = @{  
       "Authorization" = "$accessToken"     
       "Content-Type" = "application/json"  
       }

# Create the HTTP request
$ListAppsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/apps" -Headers $headers -Method Get

# Filter the apps by workspaceId
$appsInWorkspace = $ListAppsResponse.value | Where-Object { $_.workspaceId -eq $workspaceId }
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, you need to connect Power Bi account as a
> user not as a service principal.

In my case, I modified the script by passing **user's credentials** and connected to Power Bi account as a user like this:

```
$username = "admin@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "xxxxxxxxxx"

$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, (convertto-securestring $password -asplaintext -force))
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credentials

# Get the access token from the authenticated session 
$accessToken = Get-PowerBIAccessToken
$accessToken = $accessToken.Values
$headers = @{  
       "Authorization" = "$accessToken"     
       "Content-Type" = "application/json"  
       }

# Create the HTTP request
$ListAppsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/apps" -Headers $headers -Method Get
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran **`$ListAppsResponse.value`**, I got the list of installed apps successfully in **response** like this:

[image]